# How do I obtain all documents referenced by a single document?

Tags: doctrine-mongodb

If I have a document `Shop` that has many `Activities` defined as `ReferenceMany`, is there a way I can directly query for the list of `Activities` for a `Shop` without hydrating a `Shop` instance?

For example:

```
{
    "_id": fd390j09afj09dfj,
    "activities": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

All I want is to be able to say "get me the array `activities` where `_id` is *fd390j09afj09dfj*, and hydrate them as `Activity` instances.

---

Here's the first solution I came up with:

```
    /**
     * Gets all activities configured for a shop.
     *
     * @param string $shopId
     * @return \BikeShed\Domain\Activity[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function findByShopId($shopId) {

        /** @var \BikeShed\Domain\Repository\Shop $shopRepository */
        $shopRepository = $this->dm->getRepository('BikeShed\Domain\Shop');

        $shop = $shopRepository->findOneById($shopId);

        return $shop->getActivities();

    }
```

It's simply fetching the `Shop` and then getting all the `Activities` via the defined relation.

---

Here's a working example of how you would implement jmikola's last suggestion:

```
    /**
     * @param string $shopId
     * @return ActivityModel[]
     */
    public function findByShopId($shopId) {

        $partialShopData = $this->dm->getRepository('BikeShed\Domain\Shop')->createQueryBuilder()
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->field('activities')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult()
        ;

        $activityIds = [];
        if(!empty($partialShopData['activities']))
            foreach($partialShopData['activities'] as $activity)
                if(!empty($activity['$id']))
                    $activityIds[] = $activity['$id'];

        return $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('id')
            ->in($activityIds)
            ->getQuery()
            ->toArray()
        ;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly query the Shop collection or (or ODM repository) and receive Activity instances; however, you can use the [Query Builder API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html) to specify a projection with [`select('activities')`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#selecting-fields). The executed query will still return Shop instances, but the `activities` field should be the only thing hydrated (as a PersistentCollection of Activity instances). In this case, you shouldn't modify any of the non-hydrated Shop fields, as ODM will detect any non-null value as a change.

It should be trivial to add a convenience method on ShopRepository that issues the above query with its `select()` and returns the collection (or an array) of Activity documents instead of the Shop. Keeping the Shop inaccessible should also protect you from inadvertently modifying other non-hydrated fields within it.

The down-side with this method is that the Activities will be proxy objects and lazily loaded. You can mitigate this with [reference priming](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html). With priming, you'll end up doing two queries (one for the Shop and one for all referenced Activity documents).

---

Regarding your follow-up question about putting this method on the Activity repository, you do have another option. Firstly, I agree that `ActivityRepository::findByShopId()` is preferable to calling a method on ShopRepository that returns Activity objects.

Each repository has a reference to the document manager, which you can use to access other repositories via the `getRepository()` method. An `ActivityRepository::findByShopId()` could do the following:

- Access the Shop repository through the document manager
- Query for the Shop by its ID, projecting only the `activities` field and disabling hydration completely
- Collect the identifiers from the `activities` array. Depending on whether the Activity references are simple or not, the elements in that array may be the raw `_id` values or [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) objects.
- Execute a query for all Activity objects (easy, since we're already in that repository) where the ID is `$in` the array of identifiers

Comment: Would there be a way for me to return them via a findByShopId on an Activity repository?

Comment: I amended my answer to address your question. I also removed my discussion about embedded documents, as I missed that you were dealing with references originally :)

Comment: Updated my question with my `ActivityRepository` method.  Is there anything about that approach that might seem inferior to your suggestion?  Any potential gotchas?

Comment: If the Shop you are searching by is already managed by ODM (maybe returned from a previous query), your query is going to return that object directly. ODM goes to great lengths to ensure that we don't have multiple objects for the same identifier floating around. Furthermore, you'll end up selecting the Activity objects from *that* Shop instance -- even if it has unpersisted changes or new, unmanaged Activity references within. My second solution (non-hydrated query followed by `$in` query) might be more robust.